# why $f'/f$ has a simple pole with residue $k$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some confusion in Joseph Bak complex analysis Theorem $10.8$

Theorem $10.8$

> Suppose  $\gamma $ is  a regular closed  curve. If $f$  is meromorphic inside and on $\gamma$  and  contains no zeroes  or oples  on $\gamma$ , and if

> $\mathbb{Z}$= number of zeroes  of  $f$  inside  $\gamma$ ( a  zero of order k being  counted  $k$  times

> $\mathbb{P}=$ number  of poles of $f$  inside $\gamma$ (again with multiplicity)

then  $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}$$

> Proof :  Note that $f'/f$  is analytic  except  at the  zeroes  or poles  of  $f$ .If  $f$  has a zero of order k at z=a ,that is ,if

> $f(z)=(z-a)^kg(z)$  with $g(z) \neq 0$

> then $f'(z)=(z-a)^{k-1}[kg(z) +(z-a)g'(z)]$ has a zero of order $k-1$ at $z$  and  $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{k}{z-a}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$

Hence , at each zero of  $f$  of order $k$ , **$f'/f$ has a simple pole  with residue $k$**

**My confusion** : why $f'/f$ has a simple pole  with residue $k$?

**My thinking** : At  a simple pole  $a$ , the residue of $f$ is given by  $Res(f,a)=\lim_{z\to a}f(z)$

$$\implies Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a)=\lim_{z\to a} (z-a) \frac{k}{z-a}+ \lim_{z\to a} (z-a)\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$
$$\implies Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a)=k+ \lim_{z\to a} (z-a)\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} \neq k$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a)=k+ \lim_{z\to a} (z-a)\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$ is actually equal to $k,$ because $g(a) \neq 0,$ so the second summand is $(a-a)\frac{g'(a)}{g(a)} = 0.$

Comment: okay that means  $g(a) \ne 0 \implies  g'/g$ is analytic near $z= a$.Am i right ?

Comment: @jasmine Yes but continuity is enough here.